# Faults using mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I never really bothered using mod_rewrite to achieve SEO friendly names but I've always admired from a distance because I've never been good at regex.

The below .htaccess file does work, but I'm sketchy about all of it and maybe I've structured it incorrectly, furthermore it looks terrible and I know that I'm doing it wrong.

It's the very last line that has my most concerns, it sends anything other than what is matched in the first lookup to pageLoader.php and then that obviously loads the view.

Any tips, even small things would assist as this is something I want to get my head around.

```
RewriteEngine On

ReWriteRule ^css/custom.css$ PlugCMS/public/genCSS.php
ReWriteRule ^js/custom.js$ PlugCMS/public/genJS.php

ReWriteRule ^plugcms$ PlugCMS/index.php [NC]

ReWriteRule ^send-mail$ PlugCMS/public/mailhandler.php [NC]
ReWriteRule ^index\.php$ PlugCMS/public/pageLoader.php?slug=/ [NC]

ReWriteRule ^(?=^(?:(?!PlugCMS|css|js|img|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|font|fonts|sandbox|private|output).)*$)([A-Za-z0-9-]+).*$ PlugCMS/public/pageLoader.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that leaps out at me is that the normal way to avoid redirecting valid files to the pageLoader.php handler is to use `RewriteCond` like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . PlugCMS/public/pageLoader.php [L]
```

Doing it this way means that you can easily add a new file to the site without having to add to the `RewriteRule` to avoid it matching.

You usually shouldn't have to use the slug hack to get the original URL.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493075/apache-rewrite-get-original-url-in-php) for more discussion.

You may want to set a `RewriteBase` for this.  Perhaps

```
RewriteBase /PlugCMS/
```

Which would make your rewrite rules a little shorter.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess) for more discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative response, I'll look into it and provide feedback about how I went. Cheers

Comment: So pretty much all that first code block says is that if its not a valid file, and it's not a valid directory, send it to pageLoader.php, and I presume I just dump the server headers to get the requested filename, effectively replacing the need for the `?slug=friendly_name`. If I understood all that, brilliant.

Comment: @Zanderwar  Yep, you understood that.

Comment: Hey I'm have a noobish problem with, It's overwriting my other rules

`ReWriteRule ^users/validate$ public/ValidateUser.php [NC]`

Comment: `ReWriteRule ^users/validate$ public/ValidateUser.php [NC,L]` maybe?  You can always post a second question with the updated rules too.  Sometimes gives more room for discussion than comments.